# Roku disable ClosedCaptionSelectionDialog in videoplayer screen

Tags: roku, brightscript

In my video screen, the first time clicking * it opens a menu rectangle, and if again clicking * it closes that rectangle, but the problem is that when we click * the second time it opens the ClosedCaptionSelectionDialog.  How can I disable that dialog and make to hide menu rectangle when we clicked * in second time?

Answer (score 2):

Is the menu rectangle a component you're adding on top of the video?  Technically you should not use the * button to bring up such overlays; https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Remote+Control+Buttons

```
During full-screen video playback:
Only video is displayed:
The Star button reveals a Roku options menu offering users standard options, like Closed Captioning, and audio tracks.
```

If you're intending to get your channel certified by roku, you might be required to change this behavior.  You could use (for example) "up" press to first display the overlay and then you could use the star button (if needed) from within that overlay.

```
Channel UI/HUDs displayed over video:
The Star button is passed to the Channel to handle and decide what to do.
For example, Channel is displaying a mini-EPG over a video, so the Star button press would be handled by the Channel.
```

That said, without knowing more, my guess is that your code is handling the * keypress to close the overlay but not returning true, so then the keypress is rehandled upstream.

Or perhaps I'm totally misunderstanding your situation.  If so could you please post what code you added or changed to bring up the rectangle?

Comment: White playing the video in video node when we clicked * the ClosedCaptionSelectionDialog used to open but we dnt want that ClosedCaptionSelectionDialog to open when we clicked * button how can we do, that was my questation

Comment: add a keyhandler in a child below the video node and if the * is pressed, return true